# TSQL Change column name in sql select statement based on parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Updating a stored procedure and want to be able to change the name of the column returned dependant on parameter input

I understand the below is not valid but thought it the best way to explain what I want to achieve.... I want to be able to change the name of the column in the select statement dependent on a input parameter...

```
(
 CASE
 WHEN (@DateExpired = 1) THEN sens.date1 AS [Expired]
 ELSE sens.date1 AS [Due Date]
 END
)
```

I can see how I could do this at whole table select level but did not want to duplicate code for the usual reasons associated with why duplicated code is bad.  Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Is the SP called from an app? Why not let the UI handle the name of column to be displayed, unless of course another query or so depends on the column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use an IF statement in your stored procedure...

```
IF @DateExpired = 1
    SELECT sens.date1 AS Expired FROM sens
ELSE
    SELECT sens.date1 AS [Due Date] FROM sens
```

If you are worried about the duplicate SQL (perhaps because your query is complex) then you could have your SQL statement insert your required data into a temporary table and then use the IF above replacing "sens" with your temp table and just return the column names from the temp table.

Hope that helps,

Ash

Comment: Thanks - I was just about to post this answer too - this is what I went with, inserting that data into a table variable and then using the if statement as above.... did not like the idea of adding invalid data and having the app somewhere else manage this data (seemed a little messy).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add both the columns in Select List and add a dummy date which is not feasible from application when condition are not met for that column like:

```
(
 CASE WHEN (@DateExpired = 1) THEN sens.date1  ELSE '01-01-1900' END AS [Expired]
 CASE WHEN (@DateExpired <> 1) THEN sens.date1  ELSE '01-01-1900' END AS [Due Date]
)
```

and then let the client application handle the invalid dates as required by the business..